# Inventory Tape Media in Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, media, inventory

I am new to Tape. I searched to find is there any proper way to inventory the tapes that is attached to my Windows Machine. My goal is to get the basic information of tape (library,drive and media) that is attached to the windows machine .I tried the below powershell script.

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/508cf491-9cc7-48f6-a835-29a3a8559138

the problem is that i am using a Virtual Tape Library by cristalink's firestreamer.

https://www.cristalink.com/fs/

Most of the output parameters are empty. The below is the sample output

Availability:  3

Capabilities:  2 7

Capability Descriptions:

Caption:  Firestreamer Tape Drive

Compression:

Compression Method:

Configuration Manager Error Code:  0

Configuration Manager User Configuration:  False

Creation Class Name:  Win32_TapeDrive

Default Block Size:

Description:  Firestreamer Tape Drive

Device ID:

SCSI\SEQUENTIAL&VEN_CRSTLINK&PROD_FIRESTRMRDRIVE\1&2AFD7D61&0&000104

ECC:

EOT Warning Zone Size:

Error Cleared:

Error Description:

Error Methodology:

Features High:

Features Low:

ID:

Installation Date:

Last Error Code:

Manufacturer:  Cristalink Limited

Maximum Block Size:

Maximum Media Size:

Maximum Partition Count:

Media Type:  Tape Drive

Minimum Block Size:

Name:  Firestreamer Tape Drive

Needs Cleaning:

Number Of Media Supported:

Padding:

PNP Device ID:

SCSI\SEQUENTIAL&VEN_CRSTLINK&PROD_FIRESTRMRDRIVE\1&2AFD7D61&0&000104

Power Management Capabilities:

Power Management Supported:

Report Set Marks:

Status:  OK

Status Information:  3

System Creation Class Name:  Win32_ComputerSystem

System Name:  2012CN2

I read articles to inventory the tape using DPM(Data Protection Manager). But i am not sure how to execute it properly. Guide me to solve my issue. Thanks in Advance

Comment: What are you trying to achieve from inventorying tapes outside your backup system?

Comment: I am trying to build a backup system. For that i am trying to find the properties of tape media, library and drive through code (cpp if there is a need ,ready to use powershell).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I am late. But unfortunately found your question today. You might be knowing that we've 2 types of devices here. Medium Changers & Tape Drives.

Medium Changers - Robots which control tapes.
Tape Drive - A container like thing which holds tapes.

You can use this project to enumerate the list of medium changer devices & tape drives. For your information, use TapeClassGuid for tape drives & MediumChangerClassGuid for medium changers.

[MSDN Project](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/CppStorageEnum-90ad5fa9)

Once you get all the changer devices, you can get information about whole tape library using DeviceIoControl - IOCTL_CHANGER_GET_PRODUCT_DATA. Open a handle to changer device path (which you get from above project) for example : "\\.\Changer0"

Thereafter you can get information about each tape drive using DeviceIoControl - IOCTL_CHANGER_GET_ELEMENT_STATUS.

That's all. For any further clarifications/requirement of sample code, please get back to me.